# Moving textfield data from a class to another/issue when loading it into a db

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I'm trying to get the data for the username that is used to login into my app so I can insert it into DB when an appointment is created so I can use that username to show all the apointments made by that user that logged into the app.

This is the "Programaritest" table

> ```
> ID_programare | Nume | Prenume | Data | Ora | Departament | Doctor | Username | Nr_telefon
> ```

This is the accounts table where the username is saved as Unique

> ```
> ID_account | Username | Password | Email | Nume |  Prenume | Admin
> ```

**This is where the username is used :**

```
package LicentaApp;



public class LogareController implements Initializable {
 public LoginVerifier loginVerifier = new LoginVerifier();







   @FXML
   private TextField Numeutilzator; Numeutilziator is the username that I am talking about

   @FXML
   private PasswordField Parola;

   @FXML
   private Label Stare;









 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


  if (loginVerifier.Conexiune()) {
      Stare.setText("");
  } else {

      Stare.setText("Conexiune nereusita!");

  }

 }

 public void Autentificare (ActionEvent event) {
 try {
         if(loginVerifier.testaredate(Numeutilzator.getText(),     Parola.getText())) {
         Stare.setText("Autentificare reusita !");
         ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Stage StagePrincipala= new Stage();
            FXMLLoader incarcator= new FXMLLoader();
            Pane parinte = incarcator.load(getClass().getResource("/LicentaApp/Meniu.fxml").openStream());

            Scene scene = new Scene(parinte);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style1212.css").toExternalForm());
            StagePrincipala.setScene(scene);
            StagePrincipala.show();

          }
     else { 
         Stare.setText("Nume de utilizator sau parola incorect");

     }




} catch (SQLException e) {





     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 @FXML
    public void Inregistrare(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
         ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Stage PS= new Stage();
            FXMLLoader incarcator= new FXMLLoader();
            Pane parinte = incarcator.load(getClass().getResource("/LicentaApp/InregistrareUser.fxml").openStream());
            Scene scena = new Scene(parinte);
            scena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style1212.css").toExternalForm());
            PS.setScene(scena);
            PS.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

*Here I m calling the function that I made in AddProgramareController and 
passing it the username located in Numeutilzator*

@FXML 
 public void GetUsername() {
     try {
     FXMLLoader loader=new     FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/LicentaApp/AddProgramare.fxml"));
     Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

     AddProgramareController AddPr=loader.getController();
     AddPr.MyUsername(Numeutilzator.getText());


 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

}
}
     ***THis is where I save the username so I can use it to add it into the     db***
```

**Here I'm trying to add an apointment, and along with the data that I'm getting via FXML I'm trying to add the username into the table aswell**

```
package LicentaApp;



public class AddProgramareController implements Initializable {
    ObservableList Timestamp=FXCollections.observableArrayList();




@FXML
private TextField Nume;

@FXML
private TextField Prenume;

@FXML
private TextField Ora;

@FXML
private DatePicker Data;

@FXML
private TextField Departament;

@FXML
private TextField Doctor;

@FXML
private TextField Nr_telefon;

@FXML
private TextField Numeutilizator;













public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

} 

*Here's the function that I'll call in GetUsername from LogareController
 public void MyUsername(String Numeutilizator) {
    this.Numeutilizator.setText(Numeutilizator);

}

@FXML 
private void AddProgramare(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, IOException  {


    String Interogare1= "INSERT INTO programaritest(Nume,Prenume,Data,Ora,Departament,Doctor,Nr_telefon,Numeutilizator) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    String nume=Nume.getText();
    String prenume=Prenume.getText();

    LocalDate data=Data.getValue(); 

    String ora=Ora.getText();
    String departament=Departament.getText();
    String doctor=Doctor.getText();
    String nr_telefon=Nr_telefon.getText();
    String numeutilizator=Numeutilizator.getText();

    try {
        ConectaredB ConectaredB=new ConectaredB();
        Connection conexiune=ConectaredB.logareDB();
        PreparedStatement MG = conexiune.prepareStatement(Interogare1);


        MG.setString(1, nume);
        MG.setString(2, prenume);
        MG.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(data)); 
        MG.setString(4, ora);
        MG.setString(5, departament);
        MG.setString(6, doctor);
        MG.setString(7, nr_telefon);
        MG.setString(8, numeutilizator);

        MG.executeUpdate();

        // ...
   } catch (SQLException exceptie1) {
       exceptie1.printStackTrace(); 
   }


}
}
```

The error message that I am getting when trying to add a new appointment is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at LicentaApp.AddProgramareController.AddProgramare(AddProgramareController.java:103)
>
> At line 103:  String numeutilizator=Numeutilizator.getText();

So it seems it's still not loading the username for some reason.

*So basically either the way that I'm getting the username to insert it into the DB is wrong, or the actually insertion is wrong.*

Comment: `String numeutilizator=Numeutilizator.getText();`

Comment: Thank you for ur answer! That seems to make the  Sql Violation go away, but now it gives me     
     `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LicentaApp.LogareController.getText(LogareController.java:129)
 at LicentaApp.AddProgramareController.AddProgramare(AddProgramareController.java:99)
 ... 58 more`

Comment: At line 129(LogareController): `String numeutilizator=Numeutilzator.getText();`                     
                   At line 99(AddProgramareController): `String numeutilizator=Numeutilizator.getText();`

Comment: Do those classes exist? If so, do they have `getText()` functions? If so, what are they returning? The errors are telling you exactly which functions are causing the error and what is causing them. It says `NullPointerException` which means either those methods don't exist or they are returning something they are not suppose to,

Comment: The classes are posted in the question above, in LogareController i get the input from the username that is inserted by the user to login, via Textfield then i made a method that you corrected for me named get text, then in AddProgramareController ive called Numeutilizator by `@FXML
LogareController Numeutilizator=new LogareController();`, the method created in LogareController is called getText so i can use it in when i do ` String numeutilizator=Numeutilizator.getText();` in AddProgramareController

Comment: I am not really the best a java, obviously, I might confuse you more then anything, I'm sorry..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be in your `getText method` in the `class LogareController`.

You have the following:

```
public String getText() {
    TextField Numeutilizator = new TextField();
    Numeutilizator.getText();
    return null;
}
```

You are always returning null instead of the text in your textfield. You are also recreating the `Numeutilizator` variable locally within the method which will always be empty. You should be using the one you define at the beginning of your class instead. I believe changing the `getText` method to the following should fix your errors:

```
public String getText() {
    return this.Numeutilizator.getText();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Probably not (completely). The controller instance used doesn't seem to be used with a fxml...

Comment: It's the same, same lines returning as being the problem, thank you for ur answer though..

Comment: @fabian yeah you are right, was just rethinking about it and it looks like the controller isn't instantiated correctly.

Comment: Fabian, NCoop `<... xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LicentaApp.LogareController">` its Linked with Logare.FXML

Comment: @MGAMG wrong instance. See *Passing Parameters Directly From the Caller to the Controller* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/2991525

Comment: I've seen it, can't manage to reproduce it, is it the only way?

Comment: @MGAMG If you specify the controller via `fx:controller` attribute there is no other way than using `FXMLLoader.getController` after loading the fxml with the instance of the loader. (Other than using static fields to store the information, which is not a good idea...)

Comment: Ok, I'll try harder, I'll get back here if I can make any meaningful progress, meantime I'm still opened to suggestions, thank you @fabian !

Comment: @fabian I think i've managed to make the passing of the parameters, or atleast tried, but it's still not actually doing the job as expected, can you take a look, ive upldated with what I've done